# Overloaded Equals Not Working for Call

Tags: c++, class

I seem to be fixing something here as when I run my program I get the output:
Unable to disable your Grocery's information as there is no valid information at this time
No matter what I input for the Grocery Id and Name.
Below is my class definition:

```
 3 #include <iostream>
  4 using namespace std;
  5 Grocery::Grocery(){
  6         id =0;
  7         name=nullptr;
  8 }
  9 Grocery::Grocery(char* ProductName,int Productid){
 10         if (id < 0 || name == nullptr) {
 11                 id =0;
 12                 name=nullptr;
 13         }
 14         else{
 15                 name=new char[strlen(ProductName)+1];
 16                 strcpy(name,ProductName);
 17                 id=Productid;
 18         }
 19 }
 20 Grocery::Grocery(Grocery &src){
 21                 id=src.id;
 22                 if (src.name==nullptr) {
 23                         name = new char[strlen(src.name+1)];
 24                         strcpy(name,src.name);
 25                 }
 26                 else
 27                         name=nullptr;
 28 }
 29 Grocery::~Grocery(){
 30         delete [] name;
 31         name = nullptr;
 32 }
 33 void Grocery::display() const{
 34         if (id == 0 && name == nullptr)
 35                 cout<<"Unable to disable your Grocery's information as there is no valid information at this time"<<endl;
 36         else
 37                 cout<<"The Grocery's id is "<< id <<" and the name of the item is "<< name;
 38 }
 39 bool Grocery::isGreaterThan(const Grocery &src)const{
 40         if(id>src.id)
 41                 return true;
 42         else
 43                 return false;
 44 }
 45 Grocery& Grocery::Grocery::operator=(const Grocery& src){
 46         if (this !=&src) {
 47                 id=src.id;
 48                 delete [] name;
 49         }
 50         if (src.name != nullptr) {
 51                 name = new char[strlen(src.name) + 1];
 52                 strcpy(name,src.name);
 53         }
 54         else
 55                 name = nullptr;
 56         return *this;
 57 }
```

I am assuming I am fixing something rather simple in my class definition but any help would be nice.

Comment: Should it be `Grocery& Grocery::operator=(const Grocery& src)`

Comment: @PaulRooney It's *very* odd, but still valid just the way it is.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the declaration of the `Grocery` class.

Comment: Where is your implementation of `operator==`?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Grocery::Grocery(char* ProductName,int Productid){
>     if (id < 0 || name == nullptr) {
> ```

This seems to be your big problem. You're checking the not-yet-initialised `id` and `name` class members here, when you should be checking the `ProductName` and `Productid` constructor parameters.

You're likely getting semi-random garbage values for `id`, and those may happen to end up negative.

Comment: Thanks Hvd, I thought I was missing something simple :).